# Add a new row to xtragrid

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I use DevEpress' grid component. When I set `NewItemRowPosition` of `GridOptionsView` to "top", a new row showed up in grid, but when I try add new row, after entering a value for each column for a new row and when the focus leave that column value I just entered disappeared! I'm trying allow the user to add a new row to a grid and add that row in the grid and database.

Comment: Can you post your code, or error details?

Comment: problem is : after user enter value to each column for new row when focus leave that column value I just entered disappeared.

Comment: its a custom DataGridView from developer express company (devExpress)

Comment: Post your code here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible cause of error may be the

The fieldname of the column must match the fieldname of the column within the datasource.

Please check the column.FieldName property in designer view of XtraGrid and the one you provide in datasource.